# Phase portraits based on eigendirections

Tags: mathematical-modeling

Classify the fixed points at the origin and sketch an accurate phase portrait (based on the eigendirections) for each of these systems:

$$(i) \frac{dx}{dt}=36x-16y, \frac{dy}{dt}=-3x+28y$$
$$(ii) \frac{dx}{dt}=-31x+y, \frac{dy}{dt}=9x-39y$$

Completely stuck on this one, any help appreciated

Comment: Do you know how to find the eigenvectors?

Comment: yes but I'm not sure what an eigendirection is

Comment: They just mean the direction of the eigenvector.